# Can you use a sql server alias to connect to azure using active directory integrated authentication?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database

We are currently migrating to Azure managed instances.  All of our SSIS packages use server alias to connect so if we need to quickly repoint a package to another server we just change what the alias points to on the execution server.

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be working for azure MI.  I can create the alias but then when I attempt to connect to the server via SSMS I get the below error message.

```
TITLE: Connect to Server
------------------------------

Cannot connect to BRHTEST.

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Cannot open server "BRHTEST" requested by the login.  The login failed. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 40532)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=40532&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

If I go into the details of the error I can see the below which has the correct server address I put in the alias.

```
Server Name: XXXXX.XXXXXXXXX.database.windows.net
Error Number: 40532
Severity: 20
State: 1
```

Is it not possible to use an alias to connect to an Azure MI using azure active directory integrated?

Comment: Hi @Bee_Riii, If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can vote or accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched and found that only Azure SQL database and Azure Synapse Analytics (SQL DW) support [DNS alias](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/dns-alias-overview):

- A DNS alias can be used in place of the server name. Client programs
  can use the alias in their connection strings. The DNS alias provides
  a translation layer that can redirect your client programs to
  different servers. This layer spares you the difficulties of having
  to find and edit all the clients and their connection strings.

[image]

We could not find more details about server alias in Azure Managed instance document,
we will consider it's not supported usually.

It's not possible to use an alias to connect to an Azure MI using azure active directory integrated